# JDBC SQL Server Stored Procedure with ResultSet, return value, and output parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, callable-statement

I am in the process of converting an application from Jython to compiled Java.  The application uses a host of SQL Server stored procedures to do CRUD operations.  All of the procedures are defined with a return value that indicates status, and some output parameters used to provide feedback to the application.  Most of the procedures also return a result set.  I'm struggling with how to retrieve the return value and the result set and the output parameters.

I normally work with C# so the nuances of JDBC are new to me.  I've been testing with one of the procedures that does an insert to the database and then does a select on the inserted object.

Here's a simplified example procedure **just to use for the purpose of illustration**.  The actual procedures are more complex than this.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Thing_Add]
(
   @Name NVARCHAR(50),
   @Description NVARCHAR(100),
   @ResultMessage NVARCHAR(200) = N'' OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   
   DECLARE @Result INT = -1
   DECLARE @ResultMessage = 'Procedure incomplete'
   
   BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO Things (Name, Description) VALUES (@Name, @Description)

      SELECT * FROM Things WHERE ThingID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      SELECT @Result = CASE WHEN ERROR_NUMBER() <> 0 THEN ERROR_NUMBER() ELSE 1 END,
         @ResultMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()
      GOTO EXIT_SUB
   END CATCH
SUCCESS:
   SET @Result = 0
   SET @ResultMessage = N'Procedure completed successfully'
   RETURN @Result
EXIT_SUB:
   IF @Result <> 0
   BEGIN
   -- Do some error handling stuff
   END
   RETURN @Result
```

I can successfully retrieve the ResultSet using the following code.

```
var conn = myConnectionProvider.getConnection();
String sql = "{? = call dbo.sp_Thing_Add(?, ?, ?)}"

call = conn.prepareCall(sql);
call.registerOutParameter(1, TYPES.Integer); // Return value
call.setString("Name", thing.getName());
call.setString("Description", thing.getDescription());
call.registerOutParameter("ResultMessage", TYPES.NVARCHAR);
ResultSet rs = call.executeQuery();

// Try to get the return value. This appears to close the ResultSet and prevents data retrieval.
//int returnValue = call.getInt(1);
// Normally there'd be a check here to make sure things executed properly, 
// and if necessary the output parameter(s) may also be leveraged

if (rs.next()) {
   thing.setId(rs.getLong("ThingID"));
   // Other stuff actually happens here too...
}
```

If I try retrieving the return value using the line that's commented out, I get an error stating that the ResultSet is closed.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is closed.

I've been through the documentation and have seen how to do return values, output parameters, and result sets.  But how can I leverage all 3?

Comment: Not sure, but `return` values are often hassle to deal with and it's easier to just use another `output` parameter. Any case, why mess about catching errors and returning them, just let them bubble back to the client? By the way, unless triggers are involved, you can simplify the main code to just `insert ... output inserted.* values ...` instead of the extra `select`

Comment: You **always** need to call `next()` before calling a getter on result set, but the problem here is you're confusing output parameters (which are generally accessed through `CallableStatement.getXXX`) with values in the result set produced by the stored procedure.

Comment: @Charlieface I do agree, and if I was starting from scratch I'd rewrite the procedures as you suggested.  However, as this is dealing with hundreds of stored procedures that already exist and have been running in production environments for some time, I'd prefer not to rewrite them.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Not sure I follow.  I know how to get the output parameter value, the return value, or the result set; my question is about getting all 3 of them.  As you can see from the error, when trying to get the return value and then loop through the ResultSet, I get an error that the result set is closed.  If I bypass the retrieval of the return value, then I no longer get that error.

Comment: Given the order of processing in your stored procedure, I guess you need to process the result set *before* you retrieve the return value with `CallableStatement.getXXX`; but I don't have a SQL Server at hand to test that.

Comment: Actually I'd prefer to test the return value before attempting to retrieve the result set.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know this is from a while back, but we did exactly what you recommended and processed the ResultSet before getting the output parameters, and that made all the difference.

Comment: @EricH Good to hear. I posted a community wiki answer to that effect so it's more visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the order of processing in your stored procedure (insert, select, then populate result parameters), you need to process the result set *before* you retrieve the return value with `CallableStatement.getXXX`.

Answer (score 0):

The output is in the `ResultSet rs` retrieved from `executeQuery()`.

You may want to use the excute method as such:

```
    call.execute();
    String returnValue = call.getString("ResultMessage");
```

You also want to map correctly to the output type.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood the question.  I know how to get the value of the output parameter using call.execute() although I am using call.executeQuery() in my example code above.  I need to get the return value and a result set as well.

Answer (score -2):

Your connection got closed once the execute query is executed. Basically mysql jdbc connection extends to AutoCloseable implicitly. Since your result is only entity from procedure,please get the value by index 0 and do a proper index out of bound exception handling.

Comment: This is entirely incorrect. `AutoCloseable` does not mean that connections get closed automatically, it just means it can be used as a resource in a try-with-resources statement. JDBC does not specify that connections should be closed after execution of a query, and such behaviour in a driver would be a severe bug. In addition JDBC is 1-based, not 0-based, and the OP is using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel. Your answer is very helpful.